# Let A be a finite group and P be a normal p sylow subgroup. What is the connection between P and $Tor_p(A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

Let A be a finite group and P be a normal p sylow subgroup.
can there be an element $g \in A$ where $order(g) = p^x$ where x>0 and $g \notin P$   ?

what I really try to understand is the connection between a finitely generated abelian nilpotent group

$A = P_1\times P_2\times ...\times P_n$

and the group

$A/Tor_{p_1}(A)$

if the answer to the question above is no,  then does

$|A| = |P_1|* \frac{|A|}{|Tor_{p_1}(A)|}$

or more precisely does

$Tor_{p_1}(A) = P_1$?

does the answer changes when A is abelian or not?

thanks a lot

Comment: Do you mean $A=P_1 \times P_2 \times \cdots \times P_n$? Free products are never abelian.

Comment: @JustinYoung $S_3$ does not have a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Comment: @DerekHolt yes. im editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, and $p$-subgroup of a finite group must be contained in a $p$-Sylow subgroup. So, if there is an element of order $p^k$, and $G$ has a normal $p$-Sylow subgroup, any such element must be contained the $p$-Sylow group.

To see why: Let $P$ is a finite $p$-group which acts on a set $S$, and let $Px$ be the orbit of $x\in S$.  So,
$$|S|=\sum_{x\in S\backslash P}[P:P_x].$$
Here $P_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$.

Because, each $[P:P_x]$ must be divisible by $p$, we see that the number of fixed points of the action must be congruent to $|S|$ modulo $p$.

Now, let $G$ with $|G|$ such that $p|n$. Suppose $P$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ and let $N(P)$ be the normalizer of $P$.  If $H\le G$ is a $p$-group such that $H\subseteq P$, then $HP$ is a subgroup of $N(P)$. But since, $P$ must be the largest $p$-subgroup of $G$, $HP=P$ which implies $H\subseteq P$.

Now, let $S$ be the set of conjugates of $P$. Because, $N(P)$ is the stablizer of $P$ under this action, and $N(P)\supseteq P$, $|S|\not\equiv 0\pmod p$, so, $S$ must have a fixed point, say $Q$.  If we restrict the action to $H$, then $xQx^{-1}\subseteq Q$ for all $x\in H$, means $H\subseteq N(Q)$. Hence $H\subseteq Q$ by the previous argument.

Comment: im editing the question to be more percise

Comment: I'll expand my answer.

Comment: its important for me to understand also the connections with the torrison please